# Salesforce Guest user access to user profile picture

Tags: lightning-scheduler

Using Lightning Scheduler inbound guest user flow. When I debug the flow I can see the profile picture for the ServiceResource on the appointment sreen. However, when I come in using the guest user url (from Sites) I only see an avatar for the ServiceResource user. Seems we are only able to get the ServiceResource sfID from within the flow so I am able to query the SerciveAppointment's related user record to get the plain text name of the ServiceResource. However not sure how to inject the profile picture from the user record into the Service Resource on the appointment screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same scenario and figured out you have to create a new sharing rule on the 'User' object with the Guest user of the community where your flow is located.

Additionally, the Service Resource Card layout - shown on the Lightning Scheduler flow - can be modified through the Service Resource Compact layout.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Rich